# Informatica Cloud - CASE stmt

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I Want to check the data in Mapping in Informatica cloud whether data exists or not before proceed to process further..
Here is my Teradata DB query and i want to do the same in informatica cloud

```
select CASE WHEN A_COUNT = 0 THEN 'FAIL' 
            WHEN B_COUNT = 0 THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN C_COUNT = 0 THEN 'FAIL'
       ELSE 'PASS'
       END CHECK
from 
(
select SUM(case when source = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) A_COUNT,
       SUM(case when source = 'B' then 1 else 0 B_COUNT,
       SUM(case when source = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) C_COUNT
from TABL1
where source in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
) ;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABL1
(SOURCE CHAR(1), DT DATE);
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO TABL1 ('A', '01-NOV-2021');
INSERT INTO TABL1 ('A', '02-NOV-2021');
INSERT INTO TABL1 ('B', '01-NOV-2021');
INSERT INTO TABL1 ('B', '02-NOV-2021');
INSERT INTO TABL1 ('C', '01-NOV-2021');
INSERT INTO TABL1 ('C', '04-NOV-2021');
```

I don't have the luxury to put the query as source.. that's why i need to create mapping.. :(

Comment: So what have you tried so far and what specific issues are you facing? In the same way that no-one is going to write a SQL script from scratch for you, no-one is going to write an Informatica mapping for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Aggregator Transformation` to calculate the SUMs, followed by `Expression Transformation` with `IIF` function like:

```
IIF(A_COUNT = 0 OR B_COUNT = 0 OR C_COUNT = 0; 'FAIL'; 'PASS')
```